# What does "they" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid took his students to a dense forest. The monster book made
Longbottom fall to ground. Hermione turns to Harry:

> Hermione: I think **they**'re funny.
>
> Draco: Oh, yeah. Terribly funny. Witty. God, this place  has gone to
> the dogs.

What does "they" refer to?

Comment: This seems to be a miss-attributed quote (Hagrid not Hermione) which is very inaccurate and missing several lines of dialogue and context. Also, it doesn't name the work it's from, could you please [edit] to improve the question's clarity. If you're going to keep asking for basic explanations of English comprehension, our sister site [ell.se] might just be a better bet than here.

Comment: To be fair, the antecedent of "they" is a bit fuzzy at this point; what CinemaSins calls "the pronoun game." There are a number of students standing around, and it could just as well be some of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the Prisoner of Azkaban movie, just before the hippogriff lesson. Scene 10, around 32:12. Hagrid tells the students to open their Monster Book of Monsters to page 49, but when Neville tries to open his it chomps at him and he falls over. Draco and friends laugh at Neville. Hermione says "I think they're funny." It looks like she's referring to the Monster Books. That is, it's the books themselves that are funny, and Neville doesn't deserve to be laughed at.

Answer (score 7):

In the book the passage is as follows:

> He took Hermione’s copy and ripped off the Spellotape that bound it. The book tried to bite, but Hagrid ran a giant forefinger down its spine, and the book shivered, and then fell open and lay quiet in his hand.
>
> “Oh, how silly we’ve all been!” Malfoy sneered. “We should have stroked them! Why didn’t we guess!”
>
> “I — I thought they were funny,” Hagrid said uncertainly to Hermione.
>
> “Oh, tremendously funny!” said Malfoy. “Really witty, giving us books that try and rip our hands off!”

It seems pretty clear that the "they" is referring to the books. It appears that the movie merely had Hermione say the line instead of Hagrid, and made the context a little less clear.